# Mule 4 - Workday connector

Tags: connection, mule4, anypoint-studio, workday-api

i'm wanting to get employee data from Workday such as when a new hire happens, employee terms, or just an update to employee record. I'm using the HR workday connector from Workday and I believe that I configured the connector correctly, but i'm still getting a 500 error. Are there any suggestions to get my connection working?